# How to count form changes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have 4 forms divided by jQuery UI Tabs and want to count the (unsaved) form changes and display them in the Tab title.

Like an unread message count on your phone.

But how can I only add 1 for each form input and not everytime a change/keypress happens?

```
var changes = 0;

    $('#form').on('keypress', 'input', function() {
        var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');

        changes++;

        $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).find('.formChanges').text('(' + changes + ')');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see tow ways:

First Way is to use an Object (or assoziative Array) and ids for each tab

```
var changes = {sum: 0};

$('#form').on('keypress', 'input', function() {
  var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');

  if(!($(this).id in changes)){
    changes[$(this).id] = true;
    changes.sum++;
  }

  $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).find('.formChanges').text('(' + changes.sum + ')');
});
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hosc4gzr/

---

Second way is to tag the changed forms and count them when you need them

```
$('#form').on('keypress', 'input', function() {
  var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');

  $(this).attr('changed', 'true');

  $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).find('.formChanges').text('(' + $('#form[changed=true]').length + ')');
});
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6gbovvmk/

---

This isn't working code. It should give you only a hint how to realize it. You have to adopt one of this ways to your problem. I can't do it for you because i don't know the HTML code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, I have not tested this code, I have written code here directly.

// make a list of input fields and its value

```
var form_inputs={};
$('form input').each(function(){
   form_inputs[$(this).attr('name')]=$(this).val();
});
var change_counter=0;
var form_input_after_blur={};
$('form input').each(function(){
   $(this).blur(function(){
        form_input_after_blur[$(this).attr('name')]=$(this).val();
        change_counter=0;
        for(i in form_input_after_blur){
              if(form_inputs[i]!=form_input_after_blur[i]) change_counter++;
        }
        alert(change_counter);
   });
});
```